# Not able to compile source generated by the scrooge thrift plugin

Tags: scala, thrift-protocol, scrooge

My plugins.sbt is

```
addSbtPlugin("com.twitter" % "scrooge-sbt-plugin" % "4.8.0")
```

My build.sbt is

```
val finagleVersion = "6.45.0"

lazy val myProject = Project("FinagleTest", file("."))
   .settings(
   name := "FinagleTest",
   version := "1.0",
   scalaVersion := "2.12.2",
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.thrift" % "libthrift" % "0.9.2",
      "com.twitter" %% "scrooge-core" % "4.18.0" exclude("com.twitter", "libthrift"),
      "com.twitter" %% "finagle-thrift" % finagleVersion exclude("com.twitter", "libthrift"),
      "com.twitter" %% "finagle-http" % finagleVersion,
      "com.twitter" %% "finagle-core" % finagleVersion
   ),
   scroogeThriftSourceFolder in Compile := {
      val base = baseDirectory.value
      base / "src/main/thrift"
   }
)
```

Created temprature_service.thrift file in `src/main/thrift` folder

```
namespace * com.foo.temprature.thrift
struct TempratureDatum {
    1: i32 celcius,
    2: i64 timestamp
}

service TempratureService {
    void add(1: TempratureDatum datum);
    double mean();
}
```

and compiled using `sbt clean scrooge-gen compile`

but I get compilation errors

```
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to /Users/Foo/IdeaProjects/FinagleTest/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[error] /Users/Foo/IdeaProjects/FinagleTest/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/com/foo/temprature/thrift/TempratureDatum.scala:481: value _equals is not a member of object scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime
[error]       _root_.scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._equals(this, other) &&
[error]                                         ^
[error] /Users/Foo/IdeaProjects/FinagleTest/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/com/foo/temprature/thrift/TempratureService.scala:65: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Add.Args,com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Add.SuccessType]
[error]     (which expands to)  com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Add.Args,Unit]
[error]  required: com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Add.Args,com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Add.Result]
[error]           add = ThriftServiceIface(self.Add, binaryService, pf, stats),
[error]                                   ^
[error] /Users/Foo/IdeaProjects/FinagleTest/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/com/foo/temprature/thrift/TempratureService.scala:66: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Mean.Args,com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Mean.SuccessType]
[error]     (which expands to)  com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Mean.Args,Double]
[error]  required: com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Mean.Args,com.foo.temprature.thrift.TempratureService.Mean.Result]
[error]           mean = ThriftServiceIface(self.Mean, binaryService, pf, stats)
[error]                                    ^
[error] /Users/Foo/IdeaProjects/FinagleTest/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/com/foo/temprature/thrift/TempratureService.scala:248: value _equals is not a member of object scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime
[error]           _root_.scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._equals(this, other) &&
[error]                                             ^
[error] /Users/Foo/IdeaProjects/FinagleTest/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/com/foo/temprature/thrift/TempratureService.scala:373: value _equals is not a member of object scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime
[error]           _root_.scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._equals(this, other) &&
[error]                                             ^
[error] /Users/Foo/IdeaProjects/FinagleTest/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/com/foo/temprature/thrift/TempratureService.scala:524: value _equals is not a member of object scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime
[error]           _root_.scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._equals(this, other) &&
[error]                                             ^
[error] /Users/Foo/IdeaProjects/FinagleTest/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main/com/foo/temprature/thrift/TempratureService.scala:705: value _equals is not a member of object scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime
[error]           _root_.scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._equals(this, other) &&
[error]                                             ^
[error] 7 errors found
```

Comment: Any update in this issue?. I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Funny today I was writing another thrift service and I found this problem which was posted by me 1 year back :)

Luckily the solution is pretty easy.

The version of the plugin being used in code above is very old.

You can find out the latest version of this plugin here

https://bintray.com/twittercsl/sbt-plugins/scrooge-sbt-plugin

The problem gets resolved if I update the plugins.sbt file to

```
addSbtPlugin("com.twitter" % "scrooge-sbt-plugin" % "18.4.0")
```

Comment: btw, libthrift can be upped to 0.10 as well with version 18.4.0